# How can I maximize my cooldown reduction?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm trying to maximize my cooldown reduction of skills. Is there somewhere where I can find the following information?

- Is there a list of all item slots where Cooldown Reduction can spawn?
- Is there a list of all legendary items with Cooldown Reduction?

What is the maximum cooldown reduction I can achieve through gear?

Comment: So people basically do not like that someone wants to know this stuff? oO Why would anyone downvote a question like this?

Comment: You're asking a list type question that is quite broad, which is discouraged here. Its better to ask questions for a specific use case instead of basically saying, 'gimme a guide to all CDR info'

Comment: Hmm. Yet when equally broad questions are asked by people with large rep, that sometimes seems to be OK... but it is fair comment that this is multiple questions in one. Additionally, some of it is speculative - nobody can know yet what items will exist at level 70. I'd suggest perhaps condensing this to asking *one* of the above questions. Preferably not one of the list ones. So asking for the formula would seem reasonable as a question in itself.

Comment: I'd recommend splitting out the other half of your question, how cooldown on each piece of gear interact, into its own question.

Comment: @z- I don't think maximizing cooldowns is what the OP wants.  Generally, you want to _minimize_ your cooldowns.

Comment: @MBraedley psssh, semantics :P  I'll make it more clear

Comment: As this edited question now stands, surely this is speculative until the expansion is released and people have found all the items?

Comment: I was hoping someone around here was in the famili&friends RoS beta and would have some info already.

Comment: @Flyto As it stands, any answer we get *has* to be for just stock D3.  Since the patch included this affix, we can answer it, so long as it's limited to that.  If the OP wants to know stuff about Reaper of Souls, I'm afraid we don't allow questions about unreleased games.  So the best we can do is answer it for regular old D3, until the expansion is released, anyways.

Comment: So now I apparently earned a "notable question" badge for this question. Glad to see that people are googling for it. Hopefully, there will be an answer posted at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know from personal experience playing the game, cooldown reduction can spawn in seven different slots (max value for level 70 rare items given in brackets):

- Shoulders (7%)
- Gloves (7%)
- 2x Ring (7%)
- Amulet (7%)
- Offhand (7%)
- Weapon (9%)

There are no legendary items I know of which would give an extraordinary reduction to all skills (however, there are certain legendaries which specialize on cooldown reduction of single skills). But generally:

- Legendaries of same types as above (X%+1%)

Where X% is either 9% in case of weapon, or 7% for the other mentioned slots.

Apart from items, there are diamond gems, which reduce cooldown when put into a socket in a helmet. The highest tier gives:

- Flawless Royal Diamond in a helmet socket (12.5%)

Every character can get cooldown reduction from Paragon Levels through Paragon Points:

- Paragon Points (10%) - [max reachable when slightly under Paragon Level 200]

Finally, the best character class for the cooldown reduction stat is Wizard, since this class has a passive skill giving:

- Evocation (20%)

Now, we should keep in mind that even though the symbol % is used to quantify cooldown reduction, the formula which combines the different amounts from different sources is not additive but multiplicative. Therefore, for all the above contributions we get in total (assuming all legendary items):

1 - 0.8*0.9*0.875*(0.92^6)*0.9 = 0.656...

So that, apparently, the **maximal** achievable effective **cooldown reduction** is **65.6%** (generally, not talking about specific skills for which specific legendaries provide a much greater reduction).
I heared that much higher values of over 74% could be achieved during the beta. However, Blizzard nerfed many things for the release, so that this might just be one of those. If I missed something, let me know.

Comment: whaat, flawless royal is the highest?  Damn I was hoping for more tiers, I already have a few of them heh.

Comment: Oh, I really hope there are higher tiers! Just did not see any of those yet. The above answer is based on my personal experience with the game until now.

Comment: you should add in captain crimson and born set bonuses

Comment: I don't know what other classes have similar, but the Wizard is not alone in having a passive skill that gives a 20% CDR - the Monk for one has Beacon of Ytar which does the same.

Comment: While your conclusion is accurate the statement 0.8*0.9*0.875*(0.92^6)*0.9 = 0.656 is obviously incorrect. The result of the mutiplication should be 0.3438... Because it's the remaining cooldown, the reduction conclusion of 65.6% is still valid though.

Answer (score 0):

```
Shoulders (7%)
Gloves (7%)
2x Ring (7%)
Amulet (7%)
Offhand (7%)
Weapon (9%)
```

+
    Flawless Royal Diamond in a helmet socket (12.5%)
+

```
Evocation (20%)
```

= 6*7+1*9+1*12.5+1*20 = 83.5% cdr.

Comment: I believe CDR is multiplicative not additive, so it's actually `1 - (.93^5 * .91 * .875 * .8) = 44.3%` cooldown length, for a total of 55.7% CDR. I believe user70476's answer (including Paragon points and the legendary stats instead of the rares) gets to a higher CDR

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the Captain Crimson's Trimmings set.
2 pieces gives "Reduces cooldown of all skills by 10.0%".
and that for belt pants or boots where cooldown reduction is not possible ;-)